# Sublime Text source folder to another location?

Tags: netbeans, ide, sublimetext2

I am coming from Netbeans and one feature I like is copy source folder to another location. This allowed me to work on local repository files in a designated repo file seperate from my wamp/lamp/mamp server files. Than after finished I can commit and push off to github.

With Sublime Text 2, is there an option/package that allows me for projects to cop source folder to another folder much like what I just described?

Comment: You mean copy/paste a folder from the sidebar?

Comment: Bo, not manually copy/paste. In Net beans the "copy source folder to another folder" option in a project automatically syncs the files to another location; in my case, the swamp directory so I can locally test it and keep my local report separate.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I didn't found any sublime packages so I used AutoVer application which monitors some folder and backups its content to another location. I used this solution to copy html files to web root. Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the alternative for OS X or Linux?